# In Fiddler, how can I edit the session context menu?

Tags: fiddler

What I am wondering is, how can I edit an already existent item in the context menu that opens up when a session that has been selected is right clicked? Specifically speaking, I am looking to change the text for the item "Unlock For Editing" through the Fiddler2 Script Editor. This seems quite simple, but I when looking through `FiddlerApplication.UI`, the only thing I can find relating to a context menu strip is `FiddlerApplication.UI.ContextMenuStrip` and I don't see any items within the direct members. Maybe I am looking over something, but all I know is that I can't find the item for which text should be "Unlock For Editing". Also, if somebody does know what I am talking about, I have yet one more question; how can I make something happen upon the event of the context menu being opened, and without overriding the original code for the opening event method? Thank you for any help!

**Update to the earlier post:**
I have found the direct member to the `ContextMenu` that I was looking for.
The `ContextMenu` member for the session list was inside of the `SessionListView` data member for the list of sessions, which member is named `FiddlerApplication.UI.lvSessions`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say *why* you hope to do this?

Changing *existing* menu items isn't a supported action and while it's not hard to do so in a "hacky" way, that hack is very likely to break in a future update to Fiddler.

In contrast, adding *new* items to the context menu is supported and is accomplished by adding a `ContextAction` attribute on a method in your FiddlerScript.

Comment: Any way to add SubMenu in ContextMenu in the session area right click? Can not find any example :(